# use same token identification in my xamarin app to request API azure

Tags: c#, api

i use Graph client in my xamarin app and i want to use this token to request my API. Is it possible ?

```
GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        var result = await PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, currentAccounts.FirstOrDefault())
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));
```

how can i configure my API ( i use framework API c#) to use this ?

```
// GET: api/Elements
    public IQueryable<Element> GetElements()
    {
        return db.Elements;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you've read through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) and tried to make it work?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xamarin - using the same auth token for Graph and your API has no bearing on the client technology being used